# Différence entre « hypercentre » et « centre-ville » etc. ?

Tags: usage, terminologie, origine-ou-raison, préfixes

> Dans les ruelles étroites de l’**hypercentre**, à la mi-journée ils
> profitent de l’ombre... (à Toulouse, AFP ds. [LaPresse](https://www.lapresse.ca/international/europe/2023-08-19/le-sud-de-la-france-sous-un-dome-de-chaleur.php))

[Larousse en ligne](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/hypercentre/188531) dit qu'il s'agit du « centre-ville d'une grande agglomération ». Le [GDT](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/fiche-gdt/fiche/17488691/hypercentre) donne des équivalents qui réfèrent aux affaires et indique qu'il est plus restreint que le centre-ville sans parler de la taille de l'agglomération.

Peut-on préciser, indiquer quel sens du préfixe [*hyper-*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/hyper-) est employé, quelle est l'origine du mot, est-ce d'emploi récent, usuel ou technique ?

Comment: La définition 4c de CNRTL que tu as citée, c'est ce que tu cherches à clarifier ?

Comment: Et en France on a aussi le [« cœur de ville »](https://agence-cohesion-territoires.gouv.fr/action-coeur-de-ville-42) !.

Comment: @livresque Bien c'est la première fois que je vois le terme, donc je me questionne sur son origine, sa formation, et ce qu'il désigne, et les définitions de la BDL et de Larousse diffèrent substantiellement donc je veux plus de précisions. Le terme ne se trouve pas au CNRTL donc je ne comprends pas ta référence, à moi que j'aie mal regardé...

Comment: Si on en croit la carte de Toulouse https://www.google.fr/maps/place/Toulouse/@43.596978,1.4304562,2105m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m6!3m5!1s0x12aebb6fec7552ff:0x406f69c2f411030!8m2!3d43.604652!4d1.444209!16zL20vMGNiaGg?ucbcb=1&entry=ttu, « l'hypercentre » serait le quartier St-Cyprien, englobé par le méandre le la Garonne et le centre (et séparé de ce dernier  par l'allée Charles de Fitte) qui comprendrait une partie du quartier de la Patte d'Oie… l'avis des amis de Claude Nougaro https://www.paroles.net/claude-nougaro/paroles-toulouse est souhaité :-) —— PS : emploi non recommandé, …

Comment: … car un hypercentre peut être un centre commercial énorme calqué sur le modèle hypermarché.

Comment: Une rapide recherche indique que le mot a été introduit dans le Larousse en 2020... https://www.europe1.fr/culture/remontada-influenceur-tirlibibi-ces-mots-qui-font-leur-entree-dans-le-petit-larousse-3969469 Il ne figure pas dans le Robert.

Answer (score 2):

Ici, "hyper" reflète certainement le "plus haut degré" ou l'"intensité supérieure": l'hypercentre c'est le centre du centre-ville, encore plus actif, plus dense, etc.

[Google n-grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hypercentre&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) indique un usage qui commence dans les années 40, mais quand on creuse on se rend compte que cet usage concerne un objet mathématique (rien à voir avec un centre-ville, donc). On voit ensuite un deuxième pic d'utilisation à partir des années 70, et là on a un usage dans le sens "endroit qui centralise beaucoup de choses".

Comment: "Hypercentre",qui qualifie généralement les zones les plus fréquentées du centre ville, est souvent utilisé dans le cadre de réglementations muncipales concernant stationnement, interdictions diverses (consommation d'alcool, arrétés anti-SDF, ZFE, ...) ou obligations (heure de fermeture des bars, port du masque).

Answer (score 1):

> "Hypercentre", qui qualifie généralement les zones les plus fréquentées
> du centre ville, est souvent utilisé dans le cadre de réglementations
> municipales concernant stationnement, interdictions diverses
> (consommation d'alcool, arrétés anti-SDF, ZFE, ...) ou obligations
> (heure de fermeture des bars, port du masque). ([Graffito](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/53546/diff%C3%A9rence-entre-hypercentre-et-centre-ville-etc#comment113909_53548), en commentaire sous licence [CC BY-SA](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing))

Answer (score 0):

> Une rapide recherche indique que le mot a été introduit dans le
> Larousse [en 2020](https://www.europe1.fr/culture/remontada-influenceur-tirlibibi-ces-mots-qui-font-leur-entree-dans-le-petit-larousse-3969469)... Il ne figure pas dans le Robert.
> ([Guillaume31](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/53546/diff%C3%A9rence-entre-hypercentre-et-centre-ville-etc#comment113926_53546))